# Make a iphone 3 app fit the iphone 5 4-inch screen

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a Xcode project for a iphone app that has been designed to be universal and has a deployment target of 4.3. The project uses a .xib file for constructing the user interface and I am only familiar with storyboards. My goal is to make the app that only works on the 3.5 screen fit the iphone 5 4-inch screen. Do you guys have any tutorials online or tips on how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [How to Update Your Apps for the 4-Inch iPhone 5 Display](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33150/how-to-update-your-apps-for-the-4-inch-iphone-5-display).

Comment: The problem is that his tutorial only shows you how to do so with a .storyboard file. And since I'm am using a .xib file, many of his instructions are not applicable and not possible.

Comment: Sorry. It's not generally that complicated, though, so I've posted an answer describing a little about the process. You can typically use your existing NIBs, set the autosizing masks for the various controls and then toggle the main view's simulated metrics back and forth between 3.5" and 4.0" to see how it will be rendered on both.

Comment: By the way, you might also want to make sure you have retina `@2x` images (if you haven't already) in order to get the most out of the retina screens. Once you start using apps with [retina quality images](https://developer.apple.com/high-resolution/), apps that fail to do so really stick out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process is pretty simple:

1. Make sure you have a `Default-568h@2x.png` default image. See [App Launch (Default) Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) in the *iOS App Programming Guide* for information about these default images, sizes, etc. But by adding this default image, that informs iOS that your app supports the 4" screen.
2. When designing your NIBs, you can toggle the simulated metrics between 4" and 3.5" to see how the view is rendered for both:

   [image: simulated metrics]
3. You can then adjust your autosizing masks for your various controls so they resize correctly. This is an example where the margins are all fixed and it should grow as you go to 4" screen:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

"All" you have to do is properly set the struts-and-springs "autoresizing masks" in Interface Builder. The same as you'd do for Storyboards.

[image: autoresizing masks screenshot]

A friendly tip while at it: don't do storyboards except for the simplest of apps, and don't use auto layout before you're familiar with struts-and-springs and are absolutely sure you can't use struts-and-springs to do your work.

Turn off auto layout in new .xibs here:

[image: turning off auto layout screenshot]

Of course, if you have device-specific artwork (such as a background that's exactly 960x640), you'll have to do more work than that, but you're prepared for **that** piece of the puzzle, right?

Next, add a `Default-568h@2x.png` file to your project. Make it 1136x640, or if you're not covering the status bar area, make it 1096x640.